# Explain the weird behavior of fprintf() in the program, printing some unusual characters in the file

Tags: c, file, io, printf

```
int index = 0;
FILE *fptr;
fptr = fopen("File.txt", "w");

char arr[] = {'A', '\b', 'B', '\b', 'C', '\b', '\b', '\n'};

while(arr[index] != '\0'){  
    fprintf(fptr, "%c", arr[index++]);
}
```

Here the output taken from the file is

```
A|BS|B|BS|C|BS||BS|
hDC2¦v
```

The |BS| is a backspace character I have written like this for clarity.
I am not being able to understand why the second line of output is shown.

Answer (score 7):

When you initialize an array with a brace enclosed list of initializers like

```
 char arr[] = {'A', '\b', 'B', '\b', 'C', '\b', '\b', '\n'};
```

there is no explicit `\0` appended at the end of the array. So,

```
 while(arr[index] != '\0')
```

runs on false premises and access out of bound memory. It invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.7.9

> If an array of unknown size is initialized, its size is determined by the largest indexed
>   element with an explicit initializer. The array type is completed at the end of its
>   initializer list.

On the other hand, initialzing an array with a *string literal* automatically places the null-terminator in the end, as mentioned in that very chapter

> An array of character type may be initialized by a character string literal or UTF−8 string
>   literal, optionally enclosed in braces. Successive bytes of the string literal (**including the
>   terminating null character if there is room or if the array is of unknown size**) initialize the
>   elements of the array.

So, either

- add a `\0` as the last element of the initializer list
- or, calculate the *valid* number of entries yourself, like using `sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `while(arr[index] != '\0')` with `while(index < sizeof(arr)/sizeof(char))`

Comment: There is no need to divide by `sizeof(char)` (is always 1)

Comment: Better to use `sizeof arr/sizeof arr[0]`

Answer (score 0):

The last array element's value is `\n`. So instead of

```
while(arr[index] != '\0')
```

you should use

```
while(arr[index] != '\n')
```

Note there is no `'\0'` array terminator in your code. But if you define the array like this

```
char arr[100] = {'A', '\b', 'B', '\b', 'C', '\b', '\b', '\n'};
```

then the unused elements not explicitly defined, will be set to 0 and the code will work, including the `newline` output.